# Actualizar Fragment desde CardView

Tags: recyclerview, botón, fragment

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Tengo un `Fragment` en el que tengo varios `TextView` con datos y un `RecycleView`. Dentro del `CardView` del `RecycleView` tengo un `boton` para cada elemento de la lista. Quiero que al pulsar ese boton se me actualicen los valores de los `TextView` que tengo en el `Fragment`.

Poniendo en ejemplo.. el RecycleView contiene una lista de productos que he vendido. y un TextView contiene el precio total de la venta. Si al pulsar el boton del CardView quito uno de esos productos. Que actualize el valor que hay en el TextView.

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView ){
            super(itemView);
        contexto=itemView.getContext();
        txtreferencia=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtreferencia);
        txtcantidad=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcantidad);
        txtdescripcion=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdescripcion);
        txtdescripcion=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdescripcion);
        txtid=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
        btneliminar=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btneliminarpiezapedido);

        card=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardpiezas);
      // btnlocalizar=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnlocalizar);
        btneliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                borrar_pieza(Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText().toString()));
        AQUI QUIERO ACTULIZAR  LOS VALORES DEL FRAGMENT QUE CONTIENE EL RECYCLERVIEW
            }
        });
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola francisco para que tu respuesta sea bienvenida en la comunidad , te recomiendo que pongas algo de código que hayas hecho para que te puedan ayudar de mejor manera . Saludos.

Comment: Pruebe poner este código en el click del botón luego de la respuesta del servidor `FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(YourFragment.this).attach(YourFragment.this).commit();` me deja saber si le funciona

Answer (score 0):

Al final resolví el problema declarando static las vistas del fragment. Desde el boton el CardView llame aun procedimiento actualizar.

```
 btneliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                borrar_pieza(Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText().toString()));
                actuacion a=new actuacion();
                a.actualizar();
            }
        });
public RecyclerView actualizar(){

    this.listadodepiezas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    Clase_lista_piezas_pedido clase_pieza =new Clase_lista_piezas_pedido();
    ArrayList<Clase_lista_piezas_pedido> pieza=clase_pieza.Obtener_piezas_pedido(naviso);
    adaptador=new Recicle_listapiezaspedidas(pieza);
    this.listadodepiezas.setAdapter(adaptador);

    return this.listadodepiezas;
}
```